# How to transfer large file from local to remote box with auto-resume and transfer only what has changed?

Tags: linux, networking

I try the following command
rsync -av --progress --inplace --rsh='ssh' /home/tom/workspace/myapp.war root@172.241.181.124:/home/rtom/uploads

But it seems it transfers the whole file again each time I execute the command when I make a  small change in app that regenerates the myapp.war.

I want also the connection to automatically resume if connection is lost. I think this part is working.

The transfer should occur over ssh.

The connection speed is very slow and can break too so it is important that it transfers only what has changed. Of course it must also ensure that the file was correctly transfered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rsync` does handle relatively small changes and partial uploads in a file efficiently. There has been significant effort in the [rsync algorithm](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/tech_report/) towards this direction.

The problem is that WAR files are "extended" JAR files, which are essentially ZIP arhives and therefore compressed.

A small change in an uncompressed file will change the whole compressed segment where that file belongs and - most importantly - it can also change its size significantly. That can overcome the ability of `rsync` to detect and handle changes in the final compressed file.

On ZIP archives each uncompressed file has its own compressed segment. Therefore the *order* in which files are placed in the archive is also important with regard to achieving a degree of similarity to a previous version. Depending on how the WAR file is created, just adding a new file or renaming one can cause segments to move, essentially making the WAR file unrecognisable. In other words:

**A small change in your application normally means a rather large change in your WAR file.**

`rsync` is not designed to handle changes in compressed files. However, it can handle changes in your application. One solution would be to use it to upload your application files and then create the WAR file on the remote host.

A slightly different approach - that does not need any development tools on the remote host - would be to unpack (i.e. unzip) the WAR file locally, upload its contents and then pack (i.e. zip) it again on the remote host. This solution only requires a `zip` or `jar` implementation on the remote host.

Comment: Excellent idea! I did not think of this as I was thinking along the lines that rsynch has some options i am missing. After all I uncompress the war anyway on the remote host. It works much faster now.